# About "get" expressions

Tags: sentence-meaning, expressions

I want to learn English expression for conversation,
so I watch videos on the Youtube.

the sentence "I got you a present" show many times in videos.
I search "get" means on [dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/zht/%E8%A9%9E%E5%85%B8/%E8%8B%B1%E8%AA%9E/get)

there are two definitions is suitable that I think

1. to pay for something
2. to receive or be given something

Which one is better ?

Comment: The verb "get" has many meanings, only one of which is "receive".  In this context it simply means the same thing as "acquire", as in "I got a new car".  You should consult a [good English dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/) for a list of all the possible meanings of "get".

Answer (score 1):

The verb get is used to convey many meanings. Among them, you can also use it in the sense of buy/bring.

If you get someone something, it means you bring/buy something for someone. So the sentence means "I bought/brought a present for you.

I got you a present = I bought/brought you a present/I bought or brought a present for you.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Is that good English ? Can I use this expression for the exam ?

Comment: I bought you a present/I got you a present. Both are common.